# Trouble installing a software BLAT

Tags: linux, unix, installation, blat

I am getting this error when I run the make command on an executable.

```
gcc -O -g  -Wall -Wno-unused-variable  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -DMACHTYPE_ -DUSE_SSL -DCOLOR32   -Wall -Wno-unused-variable  -I../inc -I../../inc -I../../../inc -I../../../../inc -I../../../../../inc   -o fixCr.o -c fixCr.c
gcc -O -g  -Wall -Wno-unused-variable  -o /Users/andregatorano/bin//fixCr fixCr.o  ../../lib//jkweb.a  -pthread -lssl -lcrypto -lpng
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: ../../lib//jkweb.a: No such file or directory
make: *** [fixCr] Error 1
```

Is there an obvious mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My machtype was empty as discussed here https://lists.soe.ucsc.edu/pipermail/genome/2009-November/020471.html

Answer (score 0):

The error is explicit, you lack the `jkweb.a` file :

```
jkweb.a: No such file or directory
```

You have to search which package provide this file or download it somewhere.

Comment: I found the answer but this was not the case. I had an empty environmental variable.

Comment: dammit jim, which one?